# How to trim all leading and trailing whitespace from all values of a MariaDB column

Tags: sql, mariadb

I want to trim all leading and trailing whitespace (spaces, linebreaks, tabs, etc) from all values of a MariaDB column. The values may contain new-lines, and the trimming is supposed to treat the whole multi-line value as one String (basically like String.trim() works in Java).

I am aware of the TRIM() function that only trims off one character type at a time. It seems too tedious for this purpose.

I was hoping to use [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/regexp_replace/) (available since MariaDB 10.0.5) for something like

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_column = REGEXP_REPLACE(my_column, '^[^\\s]*(?s)(.*)[^\\s]*$', '\\1');
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex pattern is off, and you should just be using `\s` to capture whitespace:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_column = REGEXP_REPLACE(my_column, '^\\s*(.*?)\\s*$', '\\1');
```

### Demo

(demo shown in MySQL 8.0, as the MariaDB demo was having issues, though the only difference is that MySQL uses `$1` as the capture group instead of `\\1`)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you for the quick and fully tested answer with nice dbfiddle. In retrospect my regex pattern didn't make any sense, as I used the ^\\s, i.e. "not whitespace" where I really meant whitespace. I didn't even know about the dbfiddle site - very useful! :)

Comment: I had to turn on dotall-mode with `(?s)`: `REGEXP_REPLACE(my_column, '(?s)^\\s*(.*?)\\s*$', '\\1')`